# How do I install cinelerra?

Tags: software-installation, cinelerra

I need cinelerra for my video eediting in Ubuntu but i cant install that.
Anybody can help me?

Comment: Wow... that's a lot of information to get along with... Seriously, maybe it'd be helpful for anyone trying to help you what happens when you try to install it? Any error messages?

Answer (score 5):

open the Terminal window and type in the below commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cinelerra
```

In Ubuntu 12.04 replace the last command by

```
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

Comment: Cinelerra is now available in the Applications → Sound & Video menu.

Comment: ginoe, you should edit your question to include you comment in your answer, just click the edit link.  All expansions to your answer should be edited into the answer.  The comment section is for others to comment on your answer for correction, clarification or compliments.

Answer (score 2):

There is a PPA for that: [Cinelerra PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cinelerra-ppa/+archive/ppa)

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/41)

Answer (score 1):

You may also considering Novacut as your NLE.

[Novacut Stable Releases](https://launchpad.net/~novacut/+archive/stable?field.series_filter=precise)